# Is it possible to get AWS StepFunction status transitions as an event/callback?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

[AWS StepFunctions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html)  is a service that is basically a state-machine whose states are the execution of some form of task, usually a serverless (lambda) one.

[CloudWatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html) can be used to monitor the start/stop of a StepFunction state-machine, but these events seem to only have information about the start or conclusion (successful or otherwise) of the state-machine execution as a whole, not the progress of the execution as it steps through the individual states of the state-machine. For instance, if I have a state-machine execution where the steps are `A`, `B` and `C`, it would be nice to know when the state-machine has transitioned from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `C`, not simply that it has started or stopped.

Is it possible to receive notifications of StepFunction transitions when they occur by some mechanism, specifically the name of the state that the state-machine has moved into?  I don't want to have to poll, given that the state-machine can be long-lived.  What's the best approach here?

Comment: Actually I think there is an event emitted on each StepFunction state change. The link you added shows just examples

Comment: No, unfortunately that's literally all I see when I have a Lambda that subscribes to all events with a source of `aws.states` . If you use `SendTaskSuccess` or similar to indicate the completion of an asynchronous task then you get an event with `"detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"`, but otherwise there is nothing else. Seems more than a little bit rubbish if there is no feedback of progress of a state machine.

Comment: Why do you need to be notified when the execution enters a state?

Comment: Because it's very likely you might have an external service that needs to take action when a state machine is observed to enter a state - this means you do not need to couple the state machine with the observer by embedding the observer's logic into that of the state machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own notification using a Task state with SNS or Lambda.

Otherwise you can fetch the history of the execution by calling GetExecutionHistory.

Comment: Neither is a good solution: the first option means you need to couple all possible actions into the state machine itself, which you may not be able to do if the state machine logic is not under your control and you're just wanting to monitor the progress of a state machine's execution.  The second option implies polling and it means you will have inconsistent state: the answer you get from guerying execution history may not represent the state that was current when you got the callback.